# Zoom Webinars: How to extend end date for recurring series

Tags: zoom.us

My organization has several webinars that recur weekly. In order to avoid offering sessions too far in advance, the "End Date" for the recurring webinars is set month-to-month. However, we have recently experienced issues with some sessions extended this way not showing up on the registration page. I'm new to the webinar management team, and I was a bit confused when I went to extend a series and encountered this message:

> Registration information for the occurrences that you changed will be removed. If you uncheck this option, registrants of the changed occurrences will not see the registration email and will not be able to join the webinar.

Can someone explain what actually happens when the end date is changed and/or the above option is checked/unchecked? i.e. Are customers "un-registered" every time we change the end date? Is this the reason for our issues with customers not being able to see/register for sessions?